# anonymize multiple emails per line

Tags: regex, windows, sed

I have a tab-separated dumps of database tables and I need to anonymize all emails in those files. I am using `sed` on a Windows server. Here is a demo excerpt of a file:

```
101 some guy has this email: someguy@gmail.com
102 `someguy@yahoo.com` has backticks but (someguy@yahoo.com) has parens
103 <b>someother@gmail.com</b> is bold but "someother@gmail.com" has double quotes and {someother@gmail.com} has curly braces around it
104 'somegal@gmail.com' has single quotes
```

I first worked something out that changes all emails to `anon@anonmized.ano`. It even catches multiple emails on the same line:

```
sed -ri "s/[^{(=><`' \t,\"\"]+@[^={><`'@ \t,\"\"]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}/anon@anonimized.ano/g" *.txt
```

But though the same email can be used in multiple columns on the same line, it cannot be used on the same column on different lines. (Columns have Unique constraints.) After failing at inserting some random digits in my replacement, I thought about inserting the ID into the replacement, EG `anon101@anonmized.ano`. I worked out the following:

```
sed -ri "s/^([0-9]+)(.*[{(=><`' \t,\"\"])([^{(=><`' \t,\"\"]+@[^={<`'@ \t,\"\"]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})(.*)$/\1\2anon\1@anonimized.ano\4/g" *.txt
```

So any character `` {(=><`' \t," `` can mark te beginning of an email. The email always contains a `@` followed somewhere by a dot and two or more letters.

But now my problem is it is only catching the last email of each line, in stead of all emails on each line. Please your help here.

Comment: `grep -rli *.txt` searches for the first file's name in the subsequent files.

Comment: Then your `grep` is very nonstandard.  Try it and see: `echo 00text.txt >00text.txt` then try `grep -rli 00text.txt 00text.txt` vs `grep -rli *.txt`.  The standard way to run `sed` on all *.txt files is simply `sed script *.txt` (but if you are on Windows, all kinds of weird perversions are possible).

Comment: @tripleee I'll edit my post to simplify it, taking out `grep` and `xargs`

Comment: So to make it clear: my problem is that the regex's reference to the first group contains the ID. And the third group that contains the email address can exist multiple times, though the references only catches the last occurance.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`

```
awk '{gsub(/[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+/,"anon"$1"@anonmized.ano",$0);print >(FILENAME)}' *.txt
```

Comment: where do I state the filenames to be changed?

Comment: Redirect awk print output to the file itself. Edited answer.